# read from xml string in sql

Tags: sql, sqlxml

i want create stored proc to display last name of xml string  ''

so i tried..... following script

```
Declare @xml_string xml
set @xml_string='<Contacts LastName="jonson"/>'
select Lastname =@xml_string.value('Contacts[1]/LastName[1]','varchar(50)')
```

select statement  display NULL here .please help any one ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way on getting the attribute value from the xml.

```
Declare @xml_string xml set @xml_string='<Contacts LastName="jonson"/>' 
select Lastname =@xml_string.value('Contacts[1]/@LastName[1]','varchar(50)')
```

Comment: How to create Stored proc to display that name.can u please answer

Comment: please try and do research

Comment: Thank you for your  Help.I tried and found answerer .Thank a lot!